# Add keyboard shortcuts in react to open the edit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to add keyboard shortcuts in React. If so, how could I open the form with a keyboard shortcut? The key combination that I would like to set is `Shift + Z`. Could anyone suggest some way? Are there any external libraries. that help create shortcuts in React? Is it possible to use a shortcut to call a specific function, e.g. `setEditing ()`?

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jeqkts

```
class EditForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea onChange={(e) => this.props.handleDescription(e)} value={this.props.description}></textarea>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Todo extends Component {

  state = {
    isEditing: false
  }

  setEditing = () => {
    this.setState({
      isEditing: !this.state.isEditing
    })
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isEditing

          ? (<EditForm
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
          />)
          : (
            <li>
              <button onClick={() => this.setEditing()}>Edit</button>
            </li>
          )

        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {

      todos: [
        {
          date: '2019-12-09',
          description: 'Hello'
        }
      ],
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.todos
              .map((todo, index) =>
                <Todo
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  todo={todo}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hotkeys ?

Comment: @Taxel Is this very complicated? What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I haven't used this package before, but it looks well documented (way more detailed than you will need it), so you can just install this package and follow the documentation